# Tkinter , displaying an variable

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm using `tkinter` to display sensor information which is in the format of `300.4` and I was wondering how do I code it so the variable's value will show on the GUI?

Would it be as simple as:

```
x = sensor_value = 300.4
T = Text(root, height=2, width=30, text=x)
```

Comment: Any basic tkinter tutorial should cover this. Please search for one and follow it.

Answer (score 2):

You should show your code at least to show that you actually tried doing it.
Any tutorial over the internet can answer your question.
To get an idea of how it would look:

```
from tkinter import *

sensor_value =300.4 #said sensor value
master = Tk()
x = sensor_value #assigned to variable x like you showed
master.minsize(width=400, height=400)
w = Label(master, text=x) #shows as text in the window
w.pack() #organizes widgets in blocks before placing them in the parent.          

mainloop()
```

Comment: You can try this code. Hope you got an idea how to show text on the Window from a variable. :)

Answer (score -2):

I am sorry I was on a different machine, here is my code, I am trying to also animate it which I was going to ask for help soon.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import random
master = Tk()

canvas_width = 1000
canvas_height = 1000
w = Canvas(master, 
           width=canvas_width,
           height=canvas_height)


w.pack()
x = random.randint(0,900)
h = x + 2.5
b = x - 2.5

while True:
         w.create_rectangle(20, 45, 900, 50, fill='white')
         w.create_rectangle(20, 20, 25, 50, fill='white')
         w.create_rectangle(895, 20, 900, 80, fill='white')
         w.create_rectangle(445, 35, 450, 50, fill='white')
         w.create_text(700, 35, text="Electromagnetic Field, milliaTeslas", fill='white')
         w.create_text(900, 10, text="0", fill='white')
         w.create_rectangle(b, 50, h, 80, fill='red')
         w.update()
```

I am setting x as a random number and have the text displays at the bottom indicator.

Comment: is this solution for your problem ? if not then delete it or put in question. SO is not normal forum. BTW use master.after() instead `while True`